# using fgetc to load data into 2d array?

Tags: c, arrays, file, char

I am trying to read a file in C and storing the char in a 2D array of chars. My `ROWS` and `COL` are 10 and to my knowledge my loop should execute 10 times for each column and row. So I don't think there should be any uninitialized cell. Also I have searched similar questions and they all talk about initialization of the array as the program sometimes leaves out empty cells which contain garbage but in my case, it should not have that problem, should it?

The code that I have is this:

```
for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < COL; col++) {
        int chtr = fgetc(fp);
        if (chtr != '\n') {
            grid[row][col] = chtr;
        }
    }
}
```

**Left one** is my output but it contains random characters, however, my **expected output** should be like the right one:

[image: My output] [image: Output expected]

What could be causing this sort of behavior?

Comment: it could have \r charter? remove it not just \n. also if it is \n you put nothing in the grid[row][colum] and get original grid garbage in that position.

Comment: I checked for that but it is skipping some cells so i believe it is not `\r`. @Mquinteiro

Comment: Well just did that and when i checked for the `\r` character, it gave the wrong output. However when i do decrement the cell in case it is a `\n` character, it gives me correct output. @Mquinteiro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not *skipping* newlines, instead if you encounter newline, you're not updating that position in the map (and it contains old garbage). If you'd have had a more complicated map, you'd additionally notice that each row starts further, i.e. if your map was

```
@BCDEFGHIJK
ABCDEFGHIJK
ABCDEFGHIJK
ABCDEFGHIJK
ABCDEFGHIJK
ABCDEFGHIJK
ABCDEFGHIJK
ABCDEFGHIJK
ABCDEFGHIJK
ABCDEFGHIJK
```

You would have seen:

```
@BCDEFGHIJK
)ABCDEFGHIJ
K#ABCDEFGHI
JK.ABCDEFGH
```

and so forth.

You can loop instead until `fgetc` returns non-newline character:

```
int chtr;

while ((chtr = fgetc(fp)) == '\n') { }

// some extra error handling wouldn't hurt
if (chtr == EOF) {
    printf("Corrupted map file!\n");
    exit(2);
}

grid[row][col] = chtr;
```

Comment: You might want to make the empty body of the `while` statement more obvious with an empty block or a `continue;` statement.

Comment: I may be wrong but you are not passing any argument to the `fgetc` function.